# How to add context menu to jHtmlArea

Tags: jquery, contextmenu, jhtmlarea

I need to add a `jquery` `contextMenu` to the `jHtmlArea` so it can add keywords into the `jHtmlArea`, but i am having difficulty passing the `iframe` tag to the `contextMenu` trigger.

Here the code

```
$(function () {

    $.contextMenu({
        selector: 'iframe body', 
        className: 'data-title',
        callback: function (key, options) {
            //inserts the keyword selected
            insertAtCaret($(this).attr('id'), '{' + key + '}');
        },
        items: {
            "TestPath": { name: "Test path", icon: "" },
           ...
        }
    });

    //adding an extra button to the jHtmlArea
    jHtmlArea.defaultOptions.toolbar.push([
        {
            // This is how to add a completely custom Toolbar Button
            css: "keywords",
            text: "Insert keywords",
            action: function (btn) {
                this.contextMenu(); //Error:this.contextMenu is not a function
            }
        }
    ]);

    //just for context...
    function insertAtCaret(areaId, text) {
       ...
    }

   //setting up `jHtmlArea` for input #editor

   $('#editor').htmlarea();

});
```

I try many ways to get the 'iframe body' element with no success when click on the custom toolbar button. Also i try to move the `contextMenu` creation to inside the jHtml load event, hopping the problem was that the `iframe` loads after document ready.

Other approach that could work was to simply specify the selector 'iframe' for the context menu and then menu should pop when the user right click inside the frame.

I need some guidelines or a different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to pop the `contextMenu` from the Toolbar button. I am pretty sure that there is a way to pop from inside the iframe but i can't find it. Here my solution:

```
jHtmlArea.defaultOptions.toolbar.push([
{
    // This is how to add a completely custom Toolbar Button
    css: "keywords",
    text: "Insert keywords",
    action: function (btn) {

        var jhtml = this;
        $(function () {

            $.contextMenu({
                selector: '.keywords',
                className: 'data-title',
                callback: function (key, options) {
                    jhtml.pasteHTML("{" +key+ "}");
                },
                items: {
                    "WorkerUnit": { name: "Worker Unit", icon: "" },
                    ...
                }
            });

            $('.keywords').contextMenu(); //call it
        });
    }
}
]);
```